# Can't create content without field title

Tags: 8, entities

I wanted to remove the field title from my content because I don't need it and don't want the user to see it or create it so I remove it.

But now when trying to create new content the following error occurs:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {node_field_data} (nid, vid, type, langcode, title, uid, status, created, changed, promote, sticky, revision_translation_affected, default_langcode) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11, :db_insert_placeholder_12); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 6 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 6 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => imovel [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => en [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 1486378602 [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 1486378720 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_10] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_11] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_12] => 1 ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 770 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).

Drupal\Core\Database\Statement->execute(Array, Array) (Line: 610)
Drupal\Core\Database\Connection->query('INSERT INTO {node_field_data} (nid, vid, type, langcode, title, uid, status, created, changed, promote, sticky, revision_translation_affected, default_langcode) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11, :db_insert_placeholder_12)', Array, Array) (Line: 81)
Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Connection->query('INSERT INTO {node_field_data} (nid, vid, type, langcode, title, uid, status, created, changed, promote, sticky, revision_translation_affected, default_langcode) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11, :db_insert_placeholder_12)', Array, Array) (Line: 32)
Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Insert->execute() (Line: 917)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->saveToSharedTables(Object) (Line: 855)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->doSaveFieldItems(Object) (Line: 263)
Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doSave(NULL, Object) (Line: 392)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->save(Object) (Line: 761)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save(Object) (Line: 364)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity->save() (Line: 356)
Drupal\node\NodeForm->save(Array, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->executeSubmitHandlers(Array, Object) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->doSubmitForm(Array, Object) (Line: 585)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm('node_imovel_form', Array, Object) (Line: 314)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object, Object) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityFormBuilder->getForm(Object) (Line: 113)
Drupal\node\Controller\NodeController->add(Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 574)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
call_user_func_array(Object, Array) (Line: 139)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 62)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 38)
Drupal\webprofiler\StackMiddleware\WebprofilerMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 652)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

I already saw [Automatic Nodetitle](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) but it only works for Drupal 7 and I'm working on 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One trick you can set a default value for node title and Exclude from display.

The preferred way to do this is to use the create hook.

```
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

function mymodule_node_create(NodeInterface $node) {
  if ($node->getType() == 'node_type') {
    $node->title = 'Test12';
  }
}
```

or

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "new_content_type_node_form") {
    $form['title']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = 'Test12';
  }
}
```

[Exclude Node Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title) module for hide the title or You can check from display setting as well to hide.

Comment: In which file I have to put those hooks?

Comment: create a custom module and add this code.

Comment: Also you can add themename.theme

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) to generate titles automatically, so that user don't have to enter manually.